# Does nextjs write anything to disk when deployed in standalone mode?

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, vercel

Once the app is built and deployed using standalone mode, does it require write access to disk to store cache or any other information, and does that answer change for ssg vs. isr vs. ssr?